# How to convert Data.Text.Internal.Text to Data.ByteString.Lazy.Bytestring (Text to Lazy Bytestring)?

Tags: haskell

I vaguely recall a textual conversion table for Haskell textual type, but I can't find this anymore.

How can convert to do the conversion for `Data.Text.Internal.Text -> Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString`? Hoogle unfortunately shows no results.

Comment: Mu. The correct answer depends on the consumer (specifically, what encoding the consumer expects). This is, to a first approximation, the exact reason that we have separate types for text and bytestrings.

Answer (score 2):

The elements of a `Text` are `Char`, which are unicode code points.  The elements of a `ByteString` are eight bit words.  So in order to convert Text to ByteString we will need to choose an encoding.  This is almost always UTF-8, hence `encodeUtf8`:

```
% ghci
> :m +Data.Text
> :m +Data.Text.Encoding
> :m +Data.ByteString.Lazy
> let t = Data.ByteString.Lazy.fromStrict (encodeUtf8 (Data.Text.pack "Qi Baishi 齊白石"))
> t
"Qi Baishi \233\189\138\231\153\189\231\159\179"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL

import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as TL
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding as TL
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding as T


f1 :: T.Text -> TL.Text
f1 = TL.fromStrict

f2 :: TL.Text -> BL.ByteString
f2 = TL.encodeUtf8

f3 :: T.Text -> BL.ByteString
f3 = f2 . f1
```

Comment: Can you please add some text to the answer explaining what you. I think a basic: "you can not directly convert strict text to a bytestring, but you can first make it lazy and then convert it" might help readers to understand what is going on.